# React: How to pass an argument to a parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arguments, react-props

So I have a parent component that acts like a router to all the components in my app.

In my child `Login` component, it generates a `token` if user successfully sign in, and I want this `token` to be passed to the parent component so that it can direct the user to the dashboard, with the `token` passed to that `Dashboard` component.

My `Login`'s sign-in handling part:

```
//...
handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    let username = this.state.username;
    let password = this.state.password;

    SignInAndGetToken(username, password)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.data["code"] === 200) {
          let newToken = response.data["token"];
          console.log("token = " + newToken);

          console.log("submitting with username: " + username + " pwd: " + password);
          this.props.newLogin(newToken, username)
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
  };
// ...

// SignInHandler.js
export const SignInAndGetToken = (username, password) =>
  Axios.post(LoginPath, {
    "username": username,
    "password": password
  });
```

Parent component (`App.js`) :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Route, Switch} from "react-router";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import MyNavbar from "./components/MyNavbar";
import Register from "./components/auth/Register";
import Dashboard from "./components/dashboard/Dashboard";
import Login from "./components/auth/Login";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      token: "",
      username: ""
    }
  }

  newLogin(token, username) {
    this.setState({
      token: token,
      username: username
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <MyNavbar/>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register}/>

          <Route path="/dashboard"
                 render={(props) =>
                   <Dashboard {...props}
                              token={this.state.token}
                              username={this.state.username}/>
                 }
          />
        </Switch>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I've read [this example](https://medium.com/@kyledavelaar/updating-parent-component-state-from-children-components-in-react-2ead9b9cec9f), but it's parent function doesn't take any parameter.

Is there a way to call that `newLogin(token, username)` method from the `Login` component? Or is this logic wrong?

Comment: yes you can pass parent function as props in child like - render={(props) => <Login {...props} newLogin ={this.newLogin.bind(this)} />} as you are passing to dashboard

Comment: I would suggest you to use Redux in your application. So you can call any method through out the application.

Comment: Since Redux introduces a whole lot complexity it might be a good idea to look at React Context API (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). MOBX is also a good, simpler alternative to redux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code you need to pass newLogin function to login route like below code, 
and 
as i think this is not the proper way, what you have done 
you need to store that token in local storage so you will use that token in your entire system

```
<Route path="/login" render={(props) => <Login {...props} newLogin= {(token, username) => this.newLogin(token, username)} /> } />
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning local storage! Something i can definitely use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use React context api and warp your App with that Auth context so that it will be available in your whole app.

````
      .then(response => {
        if (response.data["code"] === 200) {
          let newToken = response.data["token"];
          console.log("token = " + newToken);

          console.log("submitting with username: " + username + " pwd: " + password);
          this.props.newLogin(newToken, username)

---------------------------------------------------------------

Here you can set this token in Auth context and as well in storage.
then redirect it to the dashboard screen using route props which is available there.

==================  *****************  ============
other approach

call callback here with tokens

        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })```


**********************************************

other approach is just pass a callback prop to this screen, as you have done with Dashboard using render function and call it with token and do stuff in App.js file. Just check for route props there*

Hope this helps
````

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is to pass the `newlogin function` you defined in the parent as a prop to the child to be in the scope so, you should define the login router to refer to the Uri as a render function rather than a string component as you did in the dashboard component

```
<Route path="/login"
       render={(props) =>
             <Login {...props}
                    newLogin= {(token, username) => newLogin(token, username)} 
             />
      }
 />
```